# WPF Textblock text does not change dynamically on combobox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-3.5, textblock

I have a MVVM app. In main WPF window I have a combox and a textblock among other controls.

When I select a value from the combobox, the textblock text should change its text value dynamically according to the item selected in the combobox (depending on the id of the selected item in combobox).

My problem is that when I select a item in the combobox, textblock text does not change, it always have the default value. Any ideas how to solve this?

I want to do this using xaml only.

**Model**:

```
public class Item
{
    #region Constructors

    public Item() { }

    public Item(int id, string desc)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Desc = desc;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Desc
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Desc;
    }
}
```

**MVVM Property in view model**:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _myItems;
public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItems
{
    get { return _myItems; }
    set { _myItems= value; }
}
```

**View**:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyWPFCombo"           
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"/>

<TextBlock Padding="5 10 0 0">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
           <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select the items:" />
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyWPFCombo, Path=Id}" Value="10">
                   <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select the old items:" />
               </DataTrigger>                               
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide two things

1) You need to set the `SelectedValuePath` of ComboBox.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="MyWPFCombo"       SelectedValuePath="Id"  
      ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" />
```

2) In `DataTrigger` you need to provide the Path as `SelectedValue` of `ComboBox` not the *PropertyName*.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyWPFCombo, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="10">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select the old items:" />
                    </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: may not the class be also INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: @Siegfried.V No need, the binding is on the Control(Element Binding), As you see we are using the property `SelectedValue` of ComboBox. Therefore No need of`INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: ok, but if we change the ObservableCollection(add/remove items) of combobox, it will be automatically updated?Excuse me but I am also using such bindings and I also ask because I don't fully master it

Comment: @Siegfried.V Good to be Curious. :) I would have agreed if the Collection was of Type List . But MyItems is of type ObservableCollection  which is a generic dynamic data collection that uses an interface "INotifyCollectionChanged". So even if add again, the collection will be updated.

Comment: @user1624552 did this solve your problem ? or you are still facing the issue ?

Comment: I see, so you mean that if my class has only ObservableCollection properties, no need to define it as  'INotifyPropertyChanged', but if my class has also strings, or int inside, so I add it? very interesting because I had a case (don't remember if List or ObservableCollection), binding was working good without 'NotifyPropertyChanged', but if I added 'NotifyPropertyChanged' it didn't work anymore, bad I don't remember it, maybe you have an idea what it could be?

Comment: In doubt I set all my classes in 'NotifyPropertyChanged' as I use MVVM in all my project(began to learn MVVM 6 months ago so I am conscious that all is not perfect...)

Comment: @Siegfried For Properties that are of `DataType` Int or String or any Class type, which needs to be reflected on the UI by binding, then we have to provide the call PropertyChanged event Via `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface. Many times it happens that both Observable Collections and other types exists on the ViewModel. In this case any how we use `INotifyPropertyChanged`. And people do add PropertyChanged even to ObservableCollecion.

Comment: @Siegfried Issue you are asking, I have not faced it yet -:). I am just guessing you may have not raise PropertyChanged Event under Set. That is what i am thinking. Because most of the time developer forget to do raise it.

Comment: @SatishPai You are using SelectedValue value in DataTrigger so SelectedValuePath="Id" is needed to set in combobox. But I think (I am not sure I have not checked) that if you use SelectedItem.Id (as jeuxjeux20 proposes in his solution) in DataTrigger instead then it is not necessary to set SelectedValuePath="Id" in combobox.

Comment: @user1624552 Yes, in order to access id value, internally it has to convert the SelectedItem's  Object and get the id. Buy if you specify the directly SelectedValuePath and provide the SelectedValue, we get the value which is directly binded to SelectedValue of Control.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding to the `Id` property of your `ComboBox`, however, this property doesn't exist there. You need to use the `SelectedItem` property to access the selected item and thus its properties :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Id, ElementName=MyWPFCombo}" Value="10">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select the old items:" />
</DataTrigger>
```